# Permissions Error when trying to read / write to a file on a raspberry pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

Error:

```
PermissionsError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './Data/Set Channel.txt'
```

**Device Info:** Raspberry pi 3 Model B+ running  the raspberry pi OS

Piece of my code:

```
dir_data = "./Data/"


with open(dir_data + "Set Channel.txt",'r+') as f:
    content = f.readline()


set_channel = content
```

**Note** This code works fine on my windows 10 device but on the raspberry pi it doesn't work and returns the error shown.

Comment: Seems like... You have no permission to the file. You could use `chmod`

Comment: Post the full stack trace and your permissions for the file (which you can get from `ls -l`). The hardware and OS are probably irrelevant.

Comment: How do I get it with 1s -1?

Comment: It's better not to use file names with the spaces (`Set Channel.txt` --> `Set_Channel.txt`)

Comment: It's not `1s -1`, it's `ls -l`. You just open a terminal in your folder and type it in

Comment: Let me guess - you write the file with a webserver to automate something?

Comment: So when I use ls -l it says -r------- with only 1 r for all

Comment: The number of dashes I think I got wrong but yeah

Comment: Type `sudo chmod +rw Set\ Channel.txt` and see if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running the python code from the Terminal?

If so try to do `sudo python yourFile.py` or if you are using python3 `sudo python3 yourFile.py`.

Consider also changing your permission on the file. Do `chmod` with `r`,`w` or `x` respectively to add read, write or execute permission. I know your program is just reading the file but try to extend your permissions.